# posgres iterate over jsonb list and select specific elements for calculaten

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, gaps-and-islands

I have a jsonb field in my PostgreSQL database with a timeline JSON.
I'm facing the problem that I want to calculate the effective time without pause. As there could be multiple `PAUSE` and `UNPAUSE` elements in the list I don't have a clue how I can calculate the pause in an efficient way and remove it from the timeline.
Here some examples of how the JSON could like
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pXjLLyEo436KDtVDEqsEaQ/1

**Schema**

```
create table tim (
  timelines jsonb
);
```

**Data**

```
insert into tim (timelines) values 
('{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1439797126251,"types":["START"]},{"date":1442906975276,"types":["STOP"]}]}}'),
('{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1439542205956,"types":["START"]},{"date":1439797116251,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1440584875070,"types":["UNPAUSE"]},{"date":1441878387065,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1442906875276,"types":["UNPAUSE"]},{"date":1442919075276,"types":["STOP"]}]}}'),
('{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1439542205956,"types":["START"]},{"date":1439792505120,"types":["STOP"]},{"date":1439797116251,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1440584875070,"types":["UNPAUSE"]},{"date":1441878387065,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1442906875276,"types":["UNPAUSE"]}]}}'),
('{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1438542205956,"types":["START"]},{"date":1438797116251,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1439584875070,"types":["UNPAUSE"]},{"date":1440878387065,"types":["PAUSE"]},{"date":1442806875276,"types":["STOP","UNPAUSE"]}]}}');
```

I was already trying out some things with `jsonb_array_elements` in combination with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, `SELECT` and `WITH ORDINALITY` but nothing worked out for me. I think I'm thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, but sadly I don't have any influence on the data model.